# AWS EMR stuck bootstrapping

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bootstrapping, emr

For a course, we are doing a basic tweet analysis using AWS EMR. I followed the steps in this document:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/gettingstarted/latest/emr/awsgsg-emr.pdf

The only modifications are that I uploaded a pre-done set of tweets and we are told to use our own config file for the NLTK. The instructor gave us the following for the custom NLTK config:

```
#!/bin/bash 
sudo yum -y install git gcc python-dev python-devel
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
sudo easy_install pip
sudo pip install -U numpy
sudo pip install numpy
sudo easy_install -U distribute
sudo pip install -U setuptools
sudo pip install pyyaml nltk 
sudo pip install -e git://github.com/mdp-toolkit/mdp-toolkit#egg=MDP 
sudo python -m nltk.downloader -d /usr/share/nltk_data all
```

I create my cluster and, when it executes, it gets to 'bootstrapping' and has been stuck there for 45 minutes. Using AMI Version 3.11.0, no Hive, Pig, or HUE.

Please let me know if more information is needed to try to diagnose this. What could cause this?

Comment: It ended up failing after 48 minutes. I am trying again with a slimmed down configuration file for the nltk.

Comment: Start with a very simple bootstrap file and add lines till you find that one that gets stuck.

Also, check and see if you don't have any ports block to the world or something. ( if you added any security group )